# Include hyperlinks in description of phone call entity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

My code generates a phone call activity in each customer lead, then records the SMS conversation between that customer and the company. The description may contain an URL to an image that the customer finds relevant.

I can put the URL as text in the description property, but I would like to transform it to a hyperlink (something like an `<a>` tag of html.) That way I can click to open it directly instead of copy pasting the URL first.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

The description field on a phone call is just a plain old text field, so you can't add any formatting or hyperlinks there.

You could make a separate field, single line of text, with a type of URL. Then the URL you input should act as a typical hyperlink.

The data types are documented at [Create and Edit Fields](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531187.aspx#BKMK_SingleLineofTextFormatOptions).

Comment: oops, sorry it was me, I didn't notice the downvote at all, it must have been unintentional. Can you edit your answer please so I can up vote you back?

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM, no worries, thought I had something wrong :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're asking about being able to have a large text area, within CRM, that is editable, but allows you to enter, or at least click on, hyperlinks.

I see two supported solutions, but both would take a lot of customization.

1. Create an HTML webresource that loads the text from the field, parses it, looking for hyper links, and then add's the correct `<a>` tagging in order for the links to be clickable.
2. Search for a client side wiki markup Text Editor widget of some sort (possibly something like http://goessner.net/articles/wiky/ ?), and then format the hyper links with the correct markup.

Comment: I am retrieving SMS text contents and image URL from a messaging API, and I want to put all those contents in the activity description with a clickable URL. How can I use HTML webresource in this context ?

Comment: If you know nothing about WebResources, here is a start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18EPZinPhLE

Answer (score 0):

None of CRM data types support native full blown html rendering. If you try to use JavaScript to update the value and try to render it as html, it would trigger a save to the database as CRM would see the attribute value as modified.